# Dynamically invoking KTRs from one KTR

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I need to have one KTR which is used to invoke multiple KTRs. 
That base KTR should be connected to MongoDB and based on the mapping in MONGODB, I need to invoke the specific KTR. 
Am I supposed to use Sub Transformation mapping? but how will i configure which KTR to be invoked?

Comment: What kind of value comes back from the MongoDB mapping? A simple string? If so, just use a Switch/Case.

Comment: The output from MongoDB is JSON..
{ "PenDashBoard" : "c:\PentDashBoard.ktr" }

Comment: How many possible .ktr files are there?

Comment: see... First ill invoke first KTR.. with input as assetId = asset1 first KTR will query the JSON  { "asset1" : "c:\1.ktr","asset2" : "c:\2.ktr","asset3" : "c:\3.ktr" } and returns "asset1" : "c:\1.ktr" 1.KTR has to invoked ..

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that I wonder weather it's better to do this as a PDI Job, or a transform. So the root of it is: will the Switch/Case step work for you or not. If not, why not? Have you investigated the Switch/Case step?

Comment: in switch case.. we can just specify target step  and not another transformation right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39718/discussion-between-brian-d-myers-and-user2572739)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to have JOB instead of mapped Transformations. Just configure first KTR in your job, whatever is the output of that KTR, set it in a variable (using setVariable) and then configure second KTR. In second KTR, configure Transformation file name as ${VariableName}. It will dynamically invoke the required KTR configured in your first KTR.